# phpexcel - using it with excel template and chart goes missing php

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel, xlsx, xlsm

Can anyone let me know if there are any other library choices available for me where I can do what I wanted.. that is open the excel template file (.xlsx or even .xlsm) in php and populate the cells and keep all the charts, pivot table, even macros, forms, buttons, etc. intact. All the php will do is just populate the cells with new data from database. In other words, using the same terminology that you have used.. please point me to the library for which I can use to "edit" workbook files.

When i try the below code.. the chart itself goes missing from the resulting file. After trying various ways.. still failed.

Thank you so much again.

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
require_once 'excel/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
require_once 'excel/PHPExcel.php';

$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
$objReader->setIncludeCharts(TRUE);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load('WorkingFile_Daily.xlsx'); 
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B11', 4)
->setCellValue('B12', 5)
->setCellValue('B13', 6)       
->setCellValue('B14', 7);

 $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
 $objWriter->setIncludeCharts(TRUE);
 $objWriter->save('WorkingFile_Daily New.xlsx');
 ?>
```

Comment: Library recommendations are off-topic here. If you're having a specific problem with PhpExcel, maybe you could ask about that instead?

Comment: I need solution in phphexcel also or in any other library

Comment: A solution to what? PhpExcel can certainly open and edit existing files; so if you're having a problem with a specific scenario, you'll need to provide details.

Comment: What about the graphs? my template file has chart built-in.. all i want to phpexcel to do is to populate values in cells and don't touch the chart. And, open the new file.

Comment: What about them? You haven't actually told us anything about what you tried, and what happened. Remember that *we are not looking over your shoulder* - we can't see any of your code, or anything you've already done, you have to show us.

Comment: I have edited my question please check and answer if possible.

Comment: So, now we have some code, but still no description of what happens when you run it, other than the vague hint in the title. Please, take a step back, remove the request for an alternative library, and explain, in detail, what the actual problem is. Ideally, explain how someone could reproduce the problem for themselves.

Comment: When i try the above code.. the chart itself goes missing from the resulting file. After trying various ways.. still failed.